# Creating Sharerpoint online communication site with app-only authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to create a communication site using PnP CreateSiteAsync extension.
When I authenticate using app-only credential the site is not created and I receive `{"SiteId":"","SiteStatus":3,"SiteUrl":""}` in the response.

Is it possible to create a communication site programmatically using app-only authentication?

Answer (score 0):

"Currently creating communication sites with an app-only token is not possible."

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1481